# Spring pdf generation

Tags: java, spring, itext

I am using spring 3 AbstractPdfView in order to generate PDF files.
I noticed Spring does not use the new version of iText (5.x.x) but uses an older version (2.1.7).

1. Why does spring does not use the new package?
2. Where can I find documentation for the old package? I don't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Are you sure that there's a class called AbstractPdfResolver in Spring ?

Comment: @Aravind, corrected in message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an other big problem with the newer versions of IText: they changed the licence.

- the old IText was LGPL or Mozilla Public License (till Java 2.1.7 and C# 4.1.6)
- the actual IText is: GNU Affero General Public License AGPL - (some customized kind of GPL) (since 5.0.0)

So at least Spring can not include IText 5.0.0 (like many other not GPL open source projects)

*by by IText - zu Geld gierig*

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is because of the change in the iText structure . Check [here](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-105924.html) for a discussion on this subject. Basically you will have to extend AbstractView like AbstractPdfView and do whatever you need.