# Spring MVC - AbstractPdfView iText jar version

Tags: spring-mvc, itext

Does Spring MVC 3.1 need a specific iText jar version to run? When I extend the AbstractPdfView class, I am getting an error on eclipse like "PdfWriter is missing..required in .class file".. I am using itext 5.1.2 version.. If I change iText version to 2.7 then that error goes away.. I want to use newer versions of iText because there are lots of new features added.. is there any workaround to this or am I completely wrong in assuming that this is a version related issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep...the class that comes with the Spring framework for handling PDF generation (AbstractPdfView) is stuck against an older version of iText (and their classes)

Here is an question regarding it:

[Spring pdf generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502177/spring-pdf-generation)

Which if you read through the responses points you to a Spring Forum thread that provides a great solution:

http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-105924.html

Basically you can create your own AbstractPdfView that uses the newest version of iText API (and classes)